# Accessibility Skiplinks: stiil needed?

Tags: navigation, accessibility

A few years ago it used to be best practice to include (visually hidden) accessibility skiplinks in websites.

```
<ul>
    <li><a accesskey="0" href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a accesskey="1" href="#content">Content</a></li>
    <li><a accesskey="2" href="nav#main">Main navigation</a></li>
    <li><a accesskey="5" href="#search">Search</a></li>
    <li><a accesskey="6" href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a accesskey="7" href="#events">Events</a></li>
    <li><a accesskey="8" href="#meta">Service navigation</a></li>
    <li><a accesskey="9" href="/sitemap">Sitemap</a></li>       
</ul>
```

Supposing that at least some semantic html5 tags are used (like nav, article).

Is this still an important feature for website accessibility or have screen readers improved that much that it can be omitted?

And: could proper WAI AREA markup replace such skiplinks; if so, is there a recommendation?

Comment: It also should be noted that Section 508 Rehab Act *requires* skip links to be implemented.

Comment: If the code example is supposed to be a list of skiplinks, you'll need a skiplink to bypass them; there are just too many of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Screen reader users no longer need skip navigation links. They can navigate web pages by skipping through the HTML heading hierarchy, and can jump to specific regions of the page using ARIA landmark roles (e.g., `role="navigation"`, `role="main"`). Just be sure your pages include these features.

That said, skip navigation links are still needed for other users, most notably people with eyesight who are navigating by keyboard (not the mouse). They are likely using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to navigate through links on the page, and it's incredibly tedious to tab through dozens of  navigation menu links to get to a link in the main content. I wouldn't overdo it - just a single link to bypass  navigation and get to the main content should suffice. Also, since the beneficiaries are users with eyesight, the link should be visible, or at least it should become visible when it receives keyboard focus.

We can stop including these links when all the major browsers provide native support for jumping to specific HTML5 semantic elements and/or ARIA landmarks with keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Skip links are links placed at the very beginning of the content of a page (must be the first focusable items). Example: `Content`, `Navigation`, `Search` links (or `Skip to content`). Also named **[bypass or quick access links](http://accessiweb.org/index.php/accessiweb-22-english-version.html#crit-12-11)**
Relevant WCAG 2.0 Techniques:

- [G1: Adding a link at the top of each page that goes directly to the main content area](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G1.html)
- [G124: Adding links at the top of the page to each area of the content](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G124.html)

The code you wrote is about the **accesskey** attribute. There has never been any official standard about which key to use to avoid annoying keyboard users and their dozens of shortcuts. There are *de facto* standard like using only numerical characters and no letter (already used by screen readers)

From W3C/WAI: [Comparison of WCAG 1.0 Checkpoints to WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/from10/comparison/) (*and WCAG 1.0 is 15 years old!*):

> Accesskeys are no longer required for conformance to WCAG 2.0. It is
>   an advisory item: Providing access keys (advisory technique for
>   Success Criterion 2.4.1 (Level A).

Thorough article from WebAIM: [Keyboard Accessibility - Providing Keyboard Shortcuts Using accesskey](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey), notably the *A Good Idea Implemented Poorly* part :)

The future is already there:
**landmark roles** is the mechanism that will replace quick access links. Just add defined `role` attributes to some elements of your content and **IF** the user has a recent screen reader, then he can navigate from one part of the page to another and also find quickly the navigation menu (it's the `nav` element with `role="navigation"` in HTML5 or in HTML4 it can be `ul` or `div` - with a list of links inside).
When will we be able to remove quick access links and rely only on landmark roles? When all screen reader users will have a compatible one. Not today.
Recent article by Steve Faulkner [Using WAI-ARIA Landmarks](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2013/02/using-wai-aria-landmarks-2013/)

Comment: Thanks Felipe for your comprehensive answer, the accesskey issue was just accidental in the code which would of course be placed on top.